# MySQL: not quoting WHERE conditions slows query execution

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

I just ran into a curious issue with MySQL. I had a very slow query, even if properly indexed, which was like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl1` WHERE `parm1` = 'taleggio' AND `parm2` = 10
```

As said both `parm1` and `parm2` had indexes. The query was taking from 0.2s up to 120s, depending on the searched values.

Then I quoted the search terms like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl1` WHERE `parm1` = 'taleggio' AND `parm2` = '10'
```

and now the execution takes **0.02s**! Why that?

Comment: no, `taleggio` is not a column or I'd have an error

Comment: you're probably right, I miscopied the statement... updating it

Comment: if you are interested  in: here is a good  online book abou indexes http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents

Answer (score 0):

First query should give you an error as you're filtering items with string, 
the datatype would be CHAR or VARCHAR.

If you you integer, in same columns, the query will rub without quotes but it will be slow because of string datatype.

Second Query is proper written,

However for more performence, 
you can also create combine index on (parm1, parm2) with

```
CREATE INDEX tbl11 ON tbl1 (parm1, parm2))
```

Comment: the first query has been running fine for months... no error thrown